# Can one html form can be split on two or more parts?

Tags: forms

Look. I got readable text flow on my webpage. There's a lot of parts of this text with option delete after sing checkbox close to each portion of text.

Can one submit button be ready to receive inputs form more than just one form? I mean it's still one form but parted.

```html
<form action="val.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="text" name="zm1">
</form>

<form action="val.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="zm2">
    <input type="text" name="zm3">
</form>

<input type="submit" value="submit" form="form1">
```

And then I got PHP post-data receive file.

```html
<?
session_start();

echo $_POST[user].'<br>';
echo $_POST[zm1].'<br>';
echo $_POST[zm2].'<br>';
echo $_POST[zm3].'<br>';

?>
```

Only first two... from first form are passing. What I should do to receive all data from all 4 fields?

Can you help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd use one `<form>` for simplicity, and use `<fieldset>`s  instead. Although it would make no difference when submitted it helps to organize sections of a big form on the front end. If you use multiple `<form>`s you'll need to separately submit each one unless you intend to use [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Comment: I just noticed a big issue: It is invalid HTML to have duplicate ID -- all ID on a page must be unique. Otherwise the browser will see the first ID then look no further because it assumes that IDs are unique so it won't go looking for another duplicate ID that shouldn't exist. That's why your server stops midway through processing form data. So for each form you have assign unique IDs (ex. `id="form1"`, `id="form2"`, etc...)

Comment: O-key. Only one id for the element, I get it! So maybe we can use class name it that particularly case? Don't you think?

Comment: Class is an excellent choice as long as you don't need to manipulate form controls on the client side so much. In plain JavaScript, id and name attributes give you a good hook into form control elements. If using jQuery, class is all you ever really need for almost any situation.